Name/author of future war sci-fi book?
Trying to find details of book read in my teens so late '80's. Narrative from a (former) soldier. Warfare takes place in another dimension/rift where tanks and weaponry etc are "thin" in order to travel within the dimension where time/space/perception is "crushed" in order to fight the protagonists. Sorry not a lot more info. Any help appreciated.

Welcome to the site! There's a checklist in the tag info page which may be helpful in jogging your memory for more details: for example, was it a novel or short story or novella? which language did you read it in, and could it have been translated? was it set in our Earth's future, or in space, or in a wholly imaginary world? Any further details could help to narrow the search.
